# How to uninstall components

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible by unchecking the installed component, to uninstall it?

I want to give the user the possibillity to uninstall an already installed component.

Comment: Yes. But you have to code that all on your own. Inno Setup won't do it for you.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: Do you have any code? I have no clue how to start.

Comment: There's no generic code to "uninstall a component". You have to show us what your component is and what does it install. And then we can show you how to undo that.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: I found a simple solution. See my answer. But there is still a minor issue. When unchecking a installed component, the setup will give a warning, that unchecking an existing component will not uninstall them. But that is not true anymore. Do you know how to disable that message?

Comment: See [Inno Setup: Suppress warning if other component selected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37631304/850848).

Comment: Thanks, added it to the answer. I love that tool :)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: Sorry, now I gave you an upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[InstallDelete]
Type: files; Name: "{app}\MyComponent.dll"; Check: not IsComponentSelected('MyComponent')
```

To suppress the warning, that *"Deselecting these components will not uninstall them."*, add the flag [`disablenouninstallwarning`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=componentssection&anchor=disablenouninstallwarning) to the component itself.